# What is the percentage sign against a particular nakshatra in panchang details of birth chart?

Tags: astrology, panchang, horary-astrology

In my Jhora birthchart it is given in the panchang section that the nakshatra is Kritika (73.21 degrees left). As per the books, one nakshatra spants about 12 degrees. Then how how this percentage more than 12 degree. What exactly is getting calculated here.

Comment: Jhora or Hora? ..

Comment: Jaganath Hora astrological charting application. But it is Hora charts.

Comment: Ok now understood

Answer (score 0):

I am using the new version and in my chart, it reads:
`Rohini (80.42% left)`. My moon is in `first Pada` and has only passed `19.58%` of Rohini and therefore has `80.42%` more of Rohini to pass before moving on to the next nakshatra.

In your chart, it probably means a similar thing about how much more of a nakshatra is left for a planet to pass through before reaching the next one.